# setText of TextView in onDraw method of a custom view in android

Tags: android, textview, ondraw

I have a custom view in my layout and I also have a TextView in the layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Tiny" android:orientation="vertical">

<my.package.drawView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />


<TextView android:text="Application Name" android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30px" android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinerLayout>
```

I set the reference to the TextView in the onCreate method of the activity and in the onDraw method of my custom view, I change the text of the TextView as follows:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    tv.setText("player score: "+score);
}
```

But setting the text in the ondraw method causes it to go in an infinite loop.
Could someone please tell me how do I update the text of the TextView in or after the onDraw method of the custom view is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a visual thing in the current view i.e. textview in this case. The entire visible region is redrawn and as part of that my.package.drawView is told to draw itself and hence the infinite loop.

Changing the visual properties in onDraw should be avoided and the design is incorrect.

Maybe you need some sort of timer to update the score or somewhere else that increases the score when something happens in the game?

Comment: currently, I am checking if the score is updated and setting it in the ondraw method. I will try setting it in the onTouch event.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly why you wanna do that?
On Draw in case of TextView will be called as soon as you change the text..

Calling setText will internally call invalidate which will finally result in call of onDraw again.

In case you want to handle just the text change then implement a `TextChangeListner` and do the need full.

**Don't put this stuff in onDraw**... onDraw functionality should be used to play around with canvas.

In case you really wanna work in onDraw, use

`canvas.drawText(String text, float x, float y, Paint paint)`

more reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean when you say it goes into infinite loop? I suggest you ensure that your custom view is indeed being redrawn as you expect it to. An easy way to do that would be to log whatever you are updating in the textView:

```
Log.d("my.package.drawView", "player score: "+score);
```

How often does this log get printed?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Abhinava's answer explains why you see the infinite loop. The down-vote was not warranted though, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You get an infinite loop because setText calls onDraw, and onDraw calls setText.
You can avoid this if you call setText only if the text has changed:

```
void setTextIfChanged(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
    if (!text.equals(tv.getText()))
        tv.setText(text);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    setTextIfChanged(tv, "player score: " + score);
}
```